# Angular - Making ui-view slide out - ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-animate, angular-ui

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way of making a `ui-view` slide out of the header when it is triggered.

Basically I have navigation buttons and a view appears when they are clicked. It is the same view for each, but with different content. I am using NgAnimate. My problems are: 1) The animation is triggered each time the button is clicked and I only want it to be triggered when the view is NOT active. 2) I want to make it slide out and push the other content down and I'm struggling with that right now. Any tips or plnkr's would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: I have created a small plnkr to show what I'm trying to do here:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/5eW6aN?p=preview

When the user clicks on link 1, 2 or 3, I want the grey box to slide out but ONLY if it is not visible. If it is visible, I just want the content to change without it sliding out.
If possible, when the user clicks "Home", I want the grey box to slide back in too.

Edit 2: added animation - still not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/5eW6aN?p=preview